# whats wrong with this test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

```
test "login logout user is not online" do
get :login, :id=>1
before = User.find(1).is_online
get :logout, :id=>1
after = User.find(1).is_online
puts before
puts after
assert before == 1
assert after == 0
```

end

```
the output is
1
0

<false> is not true.
test/functional/users_controller_test.rb:22:in `test_login_logout_user_is_not_online'
```

Comment: what is is_online defined as? Is it a boolean field?

Comment: before and after aren't strings, right?

Comment: is_online defined as binary, ok ok this is wrong but why is this not working?

Comment: Not an answer to your direct question, but you should be using assert_equal(1, before) rather than assert before == 1.  The former will tell you in your test result that "<1> was expected but result was "0".  Using assert here is just trying to assert <true>, so you have no means of knowing which assert is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only problem I could mind here is that before and after are strings:

```
irb(main):023:0> '1' == 1
=> false
irb(main):025:0> '1'.to_i == 1
=> true
```

Comment: I'm new to ruby/rails, thought probably binary is also boolean.